# Isovector Representation of $SU(2)$

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, group-representations, electroweak, isospin-symmetry

In *Electroweak Interactions* by Renton (page 407) there is the calculation of matrix elements for electromagnetic interactions/weak interactions involving nuclei:

[image]

A point of confusion for me is the reference to 8.31 is an *isovector* part of the matrix element. $\tau_3$ is a 2x2 Pauli matrix, which forms part of the spin 1/2 representation of $SU(2)$.

I thought isovector would refer to matrix elements of the spin 1 representation, involving 3x3 matrices. Have I misunderstood the language or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Both $u$ and $\bar u$ belong to the spin-1/2 representation of SU(2), so their product belongs to a direct product of two spin-1/2 representations. Inserting the Pauli matrices simply projects out the spin-1 component of the direct product. Inserting the unit matrix, on the other hand, projects out the singlet (spin-0) component of the direct product.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tomas. I'm not familiar with a direct product of representations, is this the same as a tensor product? ie you have an SU(2) rep that acts on $u$ and one that acts on $\bar{u}$ and the matrix element then transforms as the tensor product of the two, $2\otimes 2 = 3 \oplus 1$.

Comment: Why does inserting a Pauli matrix project out the spin 1 component specifically? Consider the situation where you had two spin 1 representations in the matrix element, which would decompose as $3\otimes 3 = 5 \oplus 3 \oplus 1$, what are the projection operators for the quintet and triplet parts then?

Comment: The **3** is the antisymmetric piece (the cross product!) and the remaining **5** (traceless symmetric tensor) and singlet (dot product) are the symmetric pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving out irrelevant parts, $\bar u ' \gamma^\mu\tau_3 u$ is a "piece" (the third component) of an isovector $\bar u ' \gamma^\mu {\boldsymbol \tau}  u$.

You have built this isovector (triplet rep)  out of two isospinors  (doublet reps) *u*, which transform under su(2) via 2×2 generator matrices, like the ${\boldsymbol \tau}/2$. In turn, the isotriplet you have transforms under su(2) under 3×3 matrix generators ${\boldsymbol T}$, (thus obeying the same su(2) algebra!)  essentially rotating a 3-vector infinitesimally. To see how rotating two isospinors by some angle amounts to *precisely* rotating an isovector by the very *same* angle explicitly see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/304945/66086): acting on both sides of Pauli matrices amounts to rotating their adjoint (triplet) indices by the Rodrigues formula--the sweet magic of group theory$^\dagger$.

Physicists summarize this composition of irreps by **2** ⊗ **2** = **3** ⊕ **1** , formally identical to adding two spin 1/2s to get a spin 1 and a spin 0. The triplet is the *symmetric* part of the product, enforced by the symmetry structure of the isospinors, whereas the singlet is the antisymmetric part, (e.g. $\bar u' u$. Here, you need consider the reversal of up and down components of the spinor with the telltale - sign, a feature of the *conjugate rep* of su(2)).

---

$^\dagger$   Compute 
$$
 \exp{(i{\boldsymbol \theta}\cdot {\boldsymbol \tau})}~~{\boldsymbol \tau}~~ \exp{(-i{\boldsymbol \theta}\cdot {\boldsymbol \tau})}   
=   \bigl ( \boldsymbol{\tau} ~ \cos (2\theta)+   \boldsymbol{  \hat{\theta} }\times \boldsymbol{\tau}   ~\sin (2\theta)+ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} ~ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\tau} ~  (1-\cos (2\theta))\bigr ) ~,  
$$ 
which amounts to the [Rodrigues rotation on triplet indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) by $\exp (i2\boldsymbol {  \theta \cdot T})$, since the Pauli matrices are normalized by 1/2, so $\theta$ is the half angle.